# Can I change the right axis of LTSpice to plot a variable other than phase?

Tags: ltspice

I know how to change the x and y axis, but I wanted to plot something with respect to three variables.

For example, I want to plot bandwidth with respect to quality factor, angular frequency, and variation in an amplifier resistor. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Are you trying to make the horizontal axis angular frequency?  Or you want to make one of the vertical ones angular frequency?

Answer (score 4):

In an AC analysis the right axis will show phase or group delay. I think that's all it will allow with a .ac command.

For a transient analysis it can show a number of things such as current, resistance, time, wattage. If you have an axis on each side already, say voltage and current, and you add a third trace with something like resistance or wattage it will add a another axis on the left, if it needs a fourth axis it will add another to the right, and so on.

Comment: thanks for the info....yea i was wondering about ac analysis. So if i wanted to plot a graph that shows how bandwidth varies with Q factor and angular frequency, i can plot it using transient analysis right?

Comment: If you want to plot against frequency, such as a Bode plot, you use AC analysis. Transient analysis plots against time or some parameter such as voltage or current. To plot bandwidth for different Q factors you could use AC and a .step command to step a component value that affects the Q factor.